# Why are some Pokemon useless?

Tags: pokemon-go

Hi i am looking at the CP difference between Pokemon in Pokemon Go.

Below are all second teir evolution's with no further evolution's to go. Even with Type difference the Arcanine would win every fight due to it's CP. I live in a highly populated Growlith area and don't see the point in not have 6 in my fighting squad as the rest of the Pokemon are useless?

Arcanine at 70% at 1321CP

Primeape at 80% at 888CP

Fearow at 70% at 666CP

Raticate at 70% at 598CP

Jolteon at 70% at 902 CP

Is there something i am missing towards the game that only my Arcanine's have such high CP?

Comment: I'd advise to edit the title in something like: What are the criterias for higher max CPs or something.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Thank's for the suggestion and i will probably change the title, but at this point i still think there are some pokemon that are plain useless compared to a few OP ones. And in my area Growlithe are common and i have never found a weedle or water type. So i can't find a counter to Growlithe except having a bigger one.

Answer (score 12):

You missed a few important things and you underestimate type advantages.

My Wartortle with 520 CP takes out a Golbat with 800 CP in no time. Now think what a pure water type Pokémon would do to your fire squad. The attack speed and type is at least as important as CP.

Yes, Arcanine is pretty strong, but this doesn't make it the one-and-only solution. You will want to look for Pokémon to counter your opponents by type and attack bonuses, not just by surpassing their CP.

When building a team you have to look for:

- Type (dis)advantage (0.75 x damage done & 1.25 x damage taken can be pretty painful)
- Type of attacks (including STAB)
- Attack speed
- CP

Comment: While i do understand the type difference. At my level i could max a vaporeon at about 1200 and an Arcanine at 1900. If i leave the Arcanine with bite it would still win. and once the water is out the way it would just continue to wreck everything else. Where my vaporeon would be beaten my most things except fire. While i do like my High arcanine's its the only thing in all the gyms in my area as it's to OP.

Comment: South Africa, Centurion is the place to go if you want high level Growlithe's BTW.

Comment: Until a Blastoise wreaks havoc in your gym... :)

Comment: Is STAB a thing in this game?

Comment: Yes. The factor is only 1.25 though.

Answer (score 3):

This is closely associated with the other games of the Pokèmon series:

When you look at [this list](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_base_stats_(Generation_VI-present)) you will notice that Pokémon of the other games also highly differ in their stats and so it is in Pokémon Go.

The rule is: The harder to get a Pokémon, the stronger (higher max. CP) it is. (Exceptions prove the rule.)

Arcanine is an example of a very strong Pokémon also in the other games, which can even contest in the ranking of all Pokémon (not only 1st generation).

Another example would be Magikarp: Even in higher levels the maximal CP barely transcends 100. According to this in the other games Magikarp's stats are very low.

Comment: My Problem is Growlithe are common in my area, so everyone has them and nothing can counter them well. We have no water in our area and the few that do show up have to weak CP to compete against the high CP Growlithe. Arcanine should be negged to give the other ones a chance to feature.

Comment: You have the same change for getting e.g. Lapras  out of an egg which would counter Arcanine easily.

Comment: Is Lapras not a ice? Would that not fair worse against Arcanine? 

But i do like that idea, iv got some walking to do to hatch some rares :D

But this still leaves pokemon like Primate, Sandslash usless with maxing out at 900 CP

Comment: Lapras has no real advantage over Arcanine (unless you're lucky with hydro pump), a Blastoise would. And yes, there are useless Pokémon, like Onyx, which have low CP and weak stats as well.

Comment: @Pomster yepp they are weak. Lapras has both types and Fire is ineffective against it. But sure, you shouldn't use ice attacks

Comment: I'm not sure Magikarp is a good example -- AFAIK it's a joke Pokémon with a surprise reward if you train it up anyways, not something meant for a serious fight.

Comment: @Hurkyl Also Magikarp has feelings